# After form submit in jsp, I want to see what values are sent to controller

Tags: jquery, html, forms, jsp, spring-mvc

I have a form that has a `modelAttribute` coming from a controller. I am displaying a form with the values that are coming through `modelAttribute`. But when a user makes changes to the form, and clicks on submit, I want to see what information is sent back to controller. I want to see every information that is sent to the controller. Is that possible? So far I have this:

```
<form:form id="myForm" action="/success" method="post" modelAttribute="info">
....
</form:form>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#myForm').on('submit', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();         
        var data = $("#myForm").val();
        console.log(data);
    });
});
</script>
```

Thanks

EDIT:

After I changed to `var data = $("#myForm" :input').serializeArray();` inside my function, I am able to see what values are sent, but it doesn't look neat. Any other way to do it? Thanks

EDIT 2:

After I changed to `var data = $("#myForm" :input').serialize();`, I am able to see what values are sent better than last time, but still there has be a better way for printing it in console. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I basically ran a jQuery's `.each` function to iterate over the array. Pay attention to `console.log( value.name + ": " + value.value );` line. That's how I got all the names of the objects and their values.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#myForm').on('submit', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();         
        var data = $('#myForm :input').serializeArray();          
        $.each( data, function( key, value ) {
              console.log( value.name + ": " + value.value );
            });
    });
});
```

That's my solution. But I know there has to be a clean and easy way of doing this. Please post your answer if you know how to do it. Thanks

Comment: If you only print the values to the console you can as well just look the network tab.

Answer (score 1):

Go to web network in browser and check the request body and response body..